# angular play pause programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular

This code worked for me before the angular 14 version

audio.component.html

```
 <button (click)="onPlayClick(audio)">
  {{ !isPaused ? "Play" : "Pause" }}
 </button>
<audio controls #audio>
 <source src="{{ src }}" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

audio.component.ts file

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
export class AudioComponent {
src!: string;
isPaused = false;

constructor() {}

 onPlayClick(audio: HTMLAudioElement) {
  const { paused, play, pause } = audio;
  this.isPaused = paused;
  if (paused) {
   play();
  } else {
   pause();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me in the angular 14 version

audio.component.html

```
 <button (click)="onPlayClick(audio)">
  {{ !isPaused ? "Play" : "Pause" }}
 </button>
<audio controls #audio (pause)="onPause()">
 <source src="{{ src }}" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

for audio.component.ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AudioComponent {
@ViewChildren('audio') audioElms!: ElementRef;
src!: string;
isPaused = false;

constructor() {}

onPlayClick(audio: HTMLAudioElement) {
 if (!this.isPaused) {
  audio.play();
  this.isPaused = true;
 } else {
  audio.pause();
  this.isPaused = false;
 }
}

 onPause() {
  this.isPaused = false;
 }
}
```